Dynamic library tries to link to static one
ALL,
In my configure.ac I have added following line:
AX_HAVE_QT()

and then in Makefile.am I'm doing this:
QT_CXXFLAGS = @QT_CXXFLAGS@
QT_DIR = @QT_DIR@
QT_LIBS = @QT_LIBS@
QT_LRELEASE = @QT_LRELEASE@
QT_LUPDATE = @QT_LUPDATE@
QT_MOC = @QT_MOC@
QT_RCC = @QT_RCC@
QT_UIC = @QT_UIC@

libpropertypages_la_CXXFLAGS = $(QT_CXXFLAGS) # and some other flags

libpropertypages_la_LDFLAGS  = $(QT_LIBS) # and some other flags

After running autorecong + configure + make I'm getting:
Linking dynamic library libpropertypages.so against the static library libQt5UiTools is not portable.

What is this library? What is its purpose? I think I don't need it, so how do I remove it from the link command?
TIA!!!
